# How to change default test framework in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, testng

Situation is the following: 
I've succesfully created tests in `IntellijIDEA` with `JUnit`. 
Then when I rightclick on test folder to run tests I accidentally have chosen `TestNG` instead of `JUnit`. Now when I try to run tests by right click on tests folder and clicking Run"All tests" it tries to run them in `TestNG`, but tests are not configured for `TestNG` that's why I have

> Test framework quit unexpectedly, No tests found in the package error

I searched through the internet, but didn't find anything on how to change testing framework by default.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just delete the automatically created TestNG Run/Debug Configuration (Run | Edit Configurations... action) in Run Configurations dialog for the project. Then you will again have the option to choose test framework.

**UPD:** Since 2017.3 version there is `suggest.all.run.configurations.from.context` property which you can set ([Help | Edit Custom Properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) action) to true, then IDE will show you all the configurations that are available for current context.