# Change IntelliJ default test framework for run/debug configurations

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-19

Using IntelliJ 2019.3.

I'm unable to change my default test framework for run/debugging. Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787268 I've removed all of the default Gradle test configurations, but when I go to run an individual test, IntelliJ still reverts back to using Gradle.

I can manually configure to use another test framework, but I want to change it so that I don't have to do this for every single test/class/package.

I would expect there to be an option under the Run/Debug Configurations window, but there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure IntelliJ IDEA to use the built-in runner instead of Gradle:

[image: Runner]